# Reducing the time taken to load the gmail headers

Tags: java, google-api, gmail-api

I am rendering gmail headers like FROM, SUBJECT and DATE on my web application(10 mails per page).
But as per the api of gmail we first have to call the [messeses.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) first to get the list of id's of messages first, and then call the [message.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) on each of these id's to get the actual headers.

So for first step my code is like this,

```
String link = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/" + fromMail + "/messages/?labelIds=" + mailFolder + "&maxResults=10";

//Making oauth request to get message id's
JSONObject respObj = GmailUtil.requestGetUrl(link, access_token);
if (respObj.has("messages")) msgArray = respObj.getJSONArray("messages");

if (!respObj.has("nextPageToken")) isEmptyCurrentPage = true;

// 2nd step. Iterating through each id's to get the headers.
for (int i = 0; i < msgArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = msgArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String msgId = jsonObj.getString("threadId");

    String urlLink = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/" + fromMail + "/messages/" + msgId + "?labelIds=" + mailFolder + "&format=metadata&metadataHeaders=id&metadataHeaders=subject&metadataHeaders=From&metadataHeaders=Date";
    JSONObject msgResult = GmailUtil.requestGetUrl(urlLink, access_token);

    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
    jObj.put("checkBoxVal", false);
    jObj.put("date", getHeader(msgResult, "date") != null ? UtilityClass.mailBoxDateFormatter1.format(new MailDateFormat().parse(getHeader(msgResult, "date"))) : "");
    jObj.put("from", getHeader(msgResult, "from"));
    jObj.put("fromEmail", UtilityClass.extractEmailIdFromString(getHeader(msgResult, "from")));
    jObj.put("messageId", msgId);
    }
```

Now this process is taking atleast 6 to 10 seconds to execute. How can I optimize this source code to execute a little faster. Thank you.

Comment: Try asking your question here instead: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yes I will @JanezKuhar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the API works.  You first get a list of messages and if you want details on the message then you must send a message.get.  The Api also has a standard response time there is really no way for you to speed this up.

As for optimizing your code i would suggst that you look into using the Google apis java client library which was written by google for use with their apis.  [Quick start java](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java)

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Label;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.ListLabelsResponse;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class GmailQuickstart {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Gmail API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = Collections.singletonList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS);
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = GmailQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        // Print the labels in the user's account.
        String user = "me";
        ListLabelsResponse listResponse = service.users().labels().list(user).execute();
        List<Label> labels = listResponse.getLabels();
        if (labels.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No labels found.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Labels:");
            for (Label label : labels) {
                System.out.printf("- %s\n", label.getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @DalmTo, but by using java client library will there be any change in the speed of execution or the code will be optimized? I am confused.

Comment: Not unless you think there is something wrong with your code.    While the client library may be optimized for best practice its not going to give you any better speed then what you are currently seeing.   This is a free api you are going to have to live with the speed limitations set by Google there is nothing really that you can do about it.   Threading it may help a little but i suspect that you will just end up hitting the user speed quota (Flood protection) Google only wants us to go so fast.